# Winter Bash Hat Design

Tags: support, design, winter-bash

I am curious who designs all the various hats for winter bash events on SE websites. Were these hat custom made for SE,  or did the website utilize some pre-existing content? I am really curious about the identity of designers, so I will rephrase my question in an elaborate from:

> Does the administration of [StackExchange.com](http://StackExchange.com) have a team of designers working for them, do they hire third party company, or did they buy set of pre-designed images from someone?

---

If the answer is either third party or pre-designed content, then I may as well just cut to the cheese and straightforwardly ask:

> **Who makes the hats?!**

Answer (score 16):

All the hats (for Winter Bash 2013, 2014, and 2015) were made by a single person, a freelance designer named  [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com/).

How can I tell for sure? It's clearly mentioned in the [Announcing Winter Bash 2015 blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/12/announcing-winter-bash-2015/):

> That means we owe another big thank you to amazing freelance designer [Elias Stein](http://www.eliasstein.com/), who deftly handled the conversion of all hats from crazy vague concepts into beautiful digital reality for the third year in a row, and our very own unicorn lord [balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha), who once again worked tirelessly behind the scenes to perfect the hat distribution process.

Answer (score 3):

The hats from **Winter Bash 2016** are designed from the Marketing Design team, especially by Kalina Moniquet and [Nohemi Olvera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921168/nohemi-olvera).

It is also mentioned in a blog post [It's Hat Season...Announcing Winter Bash 2016](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/):

> We want to give a special nod to everyone involved in putting it together:
>
> - The Marketing Design team for coming up with the beautiful design. With extra special thanks to Kalina Moniquet and Nohemi Olvera for the amazing hat images.